# How do you change page order in the Jekyll's Minima theme?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am a completely new Jekyll user, so I appreciate that this information may be elsewhere but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have just built a new Jekyll site and am using the the default Minima theme.

I would like to change the default page order in my navigation, and have tried entering `nav-order: 1` etc into the YAML front matter for each page.

This doesn't seem to have worked, so I imagine I need to do something else to overwrite the default settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `header_pages` in your `_config.yml`.

- [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/19)
- [Jekyll Docu](https://github.com/jekyll/minima#customize-navigation-links)

When you are using [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) (default theme of Jekyll), you can edit the [header.html](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/v2.5.0/_includes/header.html) file, and add or sort your pages.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To add, you can specify with ```header_pages:``` and then use ```- pageName.markdown```. Do this in the order that you'd like to see the pages. *Replace pageName with your file name.